# how to show null value at the end when using union all in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, null, sql-order-by

I am using this code to list numbers ASC and null values listing after the value in ms sql:

```
ORDER BY -ur.sira_no DESC
```

But if i use two select query with **"UNION ALL"** and than my query is not working.

**Error**:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

How can we order null values after the numbers using UNION ALL?

Comment: Put the `UNION ALL` query in a CTE/subquery. Then you can use expressions to order the data, instead of an explicit column in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select x.*
from ((select . . .
      ) union all
      (select . . .
      )
     ) x
ORDER BY - x.sira_no DESC;
```

However, I would recommend being more explicit:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN sira_no IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         sira_no ASC
```

in your original query.  SQL Server allows you to order by *column names* in a `union all` query, but not on expressions.

Comment: The latter would put `NULL` first, not last. `NULL` has the lowest value in SQL Server in the `ORDER BY` clause. The OP wants all non `NULL` values and then the `NULL` ones.

Comment: I do admit, having the syntax (like Oracle I believe) has of `NULLS LAST` and `NULLS FIRST` would be a nice addition the the DBMS.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I just want to ask you something. Can we use union all after the order by statement? I just want to list specific id to the end.

Comment: No, @Hallowen . `ORDER BY` is one of the final parts of an entire query. You could, however, put the query in a subquery with an `ORDER BY`, but then not having an `ORDER BY` in the outer query means that the order of the final dataset isn't guaranteed, and if it is there would likely negate the one in the subquery.